# Getting favorite count on a tweet

Tags: twitter

I'm using the twitter 1.1 api to get a the timeline of a given account. However i cant seem to find a key with the favorite count of the tweet? can it really be true that this is not part of the current api? and is there anyway to get that?

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why there *is* a `favorite_count` key in each tweet.

Try looking up `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?trim_user=1&screen_name=twitter` at https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console and check the output tweets.